# www.parse.com how to implement OR query

Tags: parse-platform

Hi Guys I am working on Parse php SDK ,Where I need to run a OR query but it does not  working   .I have read some of the article about this but did not get succcess (https://www.parse.com/questions/parsequeryequalto-or-parsequeryequalto)

This is my code

```
$query1 = new ParseQuery("Chat");
$query1->equalTo("sender", "emraanhashmi000");

$query2 = new ParseQuery("Chat");
$query2->equalTo("receiver", "emraanhashmi000");

$query3 = ParseQuery.orQueries($query1,$query2);
$result = $query3->find();
```

Please suggest me how can I run Or query in php

Answer (score 0):

Given that `$query1` and `$query2` gives you the result you expect, you should use the following syntax to OR them together.

```
$query3 = ParseQuery::orQueries([$query1, $query2]);
$result = $query3->find();
```

Also, remember that parse.com is closing down and you should migrate to the open-source "[parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server)" ASAP.

Comment: Hi, glad it worked, please close this questions by accepting the answer.